# "webUrl" coming as null when sending an file invitation - Graph API (Send a sharing invitation)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I'm Using an invite API from MS GRAPH - [Invite LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Send a sharing invitation – External users

- POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/invite
- POST /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/invite

The responses from the above request  returns 200 OK response code and a [permission](https://eur02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fgraph%2Fapi%2Fresources%2Fpermission%3Fview%3Dgraph-rest-1.0&data=02%7C01%7C%7C6ff75fa34d564043cfae08d80157734a%7C9c230f7cb8904c309f79d32c2ba39bd4%7C0%7C0%7C637260822392496445&sdata=1iV%2BvjBgP1cGH9J5LIff7kWahgVgtUcFCXMZ8dR52n8%3D&reserved=0) object is returned , but the Sharing link(webUrl) under the link object returns “null” most of the times due to which the shareable link cannot be shared to External user for editing the document.

REQUEST BODY:

```
    {
    "recipients": [
        {
          "email": "abc@abc.com"
        }
      ],
      "message": "Here's the file that we're collaborating on.",
      "requireSignIn": true,
      "sendInvitation": false,
      "roles": [ "write" ]
    }
```

Here i don't want to share the item throgh mail hence making sendInvitation false and using the webURL recevied from response for collaboration.

Observation : 
It works with gmail and outlook account.
For business accounts it's not working receiving url as null.

Samples:

- If i invite for the first time , i'm getting below response ,

Sample Excepted Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(permission)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.permission",
            "roles": [
                "write"
            ],
            "grantedToIdentities": [
                {
                    "user": {
                        "email": "#####@####.com"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "invitation": {
                "signInRequired": true
            },
            "link": {
                "type": "edit",
                "webUrl": "https://**********encryptedURL*****/"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

- From the second time **link** object not coming in the response,

Sample Response Received Without webURL:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(permission)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.permission",
            "id": "###############",
            "roles": [
                "write"
            ],
            "grantedTo": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "######@######.com",
                    "id": "#############",
                    "displayName": "@@@@@@@"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved my problem by using the upload API [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
, once upload is successful the API returns [response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#json-representation) which will have "webUrl" link that can be used to share from second time.

> (After exploring more with MS GRAPH API's observed that if we are
> sharing the same file multiple times it will not give any new link as
> the old link only can be used )

Actual Flow : Upload File -> Share File (this was happening everytime)

Changed Logic : First time : Upload File -> Share file

Second Time onwards : as file is already shared , using the url from upload API Response

As file is already shared with user for the first time hence the url which we are getting as response from UPLOAD API  can be used , this url can be accessible by already shared user.

So i changed my logic if the user performing the operation for first time then i'm uploading file and sharing with him , if the user wants to perform same operation again instead of sharing the file again using the upload response url it works for me.

Posting this solution as it might help someone